# How to merge mongo inline documents

Tags: mongodb

```
[{
        "field1" : "1",
        "field2" : [ 
            {
                "f1" : "a",
                "f2" : "b"
            }, 
            {
                "f1" : "aa",
                "f2" : "bb"
            }
        ]
},

{
        "field1" : "2",
        "field2" : [ 
            {
                "f1" : "c",
                "f2" : "d"
            }, 
            {
                "f1" : "cc",
                "f2" : "dd"
            }
        ]
    }]
```

I want to find out the fields 2 and merge them into the document to the following format:

```
    {
        "f1" : "a",
        "f2" : "b"
    }, 
    {
        "f1" : "aa",
        "f2" : "bb"
    }，
    {
        "f1" : "c",
        "f2" : "d"
    }, 
    {
        "f1" : "cc",
        "f2" : "dd"
    }
```

Comment: Is not 100% clear what you wanna ask ! Give more info.

Comment: I want to merge the fields 2 into the documents below and remove the other information.

Comment: do you need an array of those fields?

Comment: yes,don't need other fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no need to `group`. Just `unwind` and `replaceRoot`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{"$unwind": "$field2"},
{"$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$field2" }}
])
```

Comment: Ok. When you are free just take a look on mongo aggregation functions. A lot of powerful pipeline stages are there. And very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

For input data:

```
[
{
    "field1" : "1",
    "field2" : [ 
        {
            "f1" : "a",
            "f2" : "b"
        }, 
        {
            "f1" : "aa",
            "f2" : "bb"
        }
    ]
}
,
{
    "field1" : "2",
    "field2" : [ 
        {
            "f1" : "c",
            "f2" : "d"
        }, 
        {
            "f1" : "cc",
            "f2" : "dd"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

use aggregation:

```
[
  {
    "$unwind": "$field2"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$field2"
    }
  },
   {
     "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$_id" }
   }
]
```

to produce:

```
[
  {
    "f1": "c",
    "f2": "d"
  },
  {
    "f1": "cc",
    "f2": "dd"
  },
  {
    "f1": "aa",
    "f2": "bb"
  },
  {
    "f1": "a",
    "f2": "b"
  }
]
```

You can play with this on mongoDB playground: [here](https://play.db-ai.co/m/XItsz6BXLQABKlTe)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let fakeArray = [
                    {
                        "field1" : "1",
                        "field2" : [ 
                            {
                                "f1" : "a",
                                "f2" : "b"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "f1" : "aa",
                                "f2" : "bb"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "field1" : "2",
                        "field2" : [ 
                            {
                                "f1" : "c",
                                "f2" : "d"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "f1" : "cc",
                                "f2" : "dd"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ];

                let arr = fakeArray.map(el => {
                    return el.field2;
                });

                console.log(arr.flat(1));
```

you can easily use js features like [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `$unwind` and a `$project` within an aggregation query:

```
db.test.insertMany([
    { "field1" : "1", "field2" : [ { "f1" : "a", "f2" : "b" }, { "f1" : "aa", "f2" : "bb" } ] },
    { "field1" : "2", "field2" : [ { "f1" : "c", "f2" : "d" }, { "f1" : "cc", "f2" : "dd" } ] }
]);

db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$field2"},
    {$project: {
        "f1": "$field2.f1",
        "f2": "$field2.f2"
    }}
]);
```

This will give you the following output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c8b70474c52159bf9357567"), "f1" : "a", "f2" : "b" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c8b70474c52159bf9357567"), "f1" : "aa", "f2" : "bb" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c8b70474c52159bf9357568"), "f1" : "c", "f2" : "d" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c8b70474c52159bf9357568"), "f1" : "cc", "f2" : "dd" }
```

https://play.db-ai.co/m/XItxEAgjhgAB8iV6

Comment: I thought about this before, but field2 has multiple properties that require more commands. $replaceRoot is more useful.

Comment: @qwx totally agree, if you have a lot of properties just replace the root document. 